# Does Apache Cordova and/or PhoneGap support Client Certificates?

Tags: cordova, client-certificates

I want to use client certificate authentication from a Cordova/PhoneGap app. Can I do this for Android and/or iOS? I'm looking for some examples...

I found [this](http://blog.xdumaine.com/authenticating-an-http-request-with-client-certificates-in-ios/) example but maybe something is built-in by now.

Comment: no, there is nothing built in, you'll have to create a plugin to handle connections with client certificates and use it to communicate with the server instead of using ajax

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on IBM developerWorks which I have found helpful; it doesn't specifically address implementing [ClientCertRequest on Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ClientCertRequest.html), however it does touch on the process of implementing a [Cordova plugin that works with WebView](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/apache_cordova_working_with_certificates_on_android?lang=en), so it may be of assistance.